# s3fs gives me an empty directory

Tags: linux, amazon-s3, fuse, fedora-17

I built s3fs, and now I'm getting an empty directory where I mounted the s3 bucket.  I put a text file in the directory, and I can see it in there, and it transfers into the bucket.  How can I see the files uploaded from other sources?  I'm running Fedora 17 on ec2, if that makes any difference.